# Redshift schema not in information_schema.schemata

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a schema called `lake` and when I run

```
select schema_name
from information_schema.schemata
```

`lake` is not in the results. I found out about this when an Amazon utility script started failing. All other schemas (including any I create now) show up there. I thought all schemas were supposed to be there?

Comment: postgres<>redshift please remove one tag.

Answer (score 0):

All schemas are visible to superusers. For other users it depends on who created the schema and whether you have permissions on it.

Try altering the schema owner to be the same as the other schemas you can see. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_SCHEMA.html

```
alter schema us_sales
owner to dwuser;
```

Comment: Changing the owner did solve the problem. But I'm running the query as master. Shouldn't I be able to see everything anyway?